# Browser not including cookies for cross-origin requests sent to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, browser, cors, http-headers

**context**

I currently have a Ruby on Rails website, using the Devise gem for session management.

I am building a standalone Chrome browser extension, but would like to reuse the authentication mechanism of my existing RoR website and share user sessions i.e. if the user is logged in on the website, he will be logged in in the browser extension, and vice versa.

To achieve this, I am sending a cross-origin request from the browser extension to my Rails server (say `/browser-extension/auth`) to validate auth status. I wish to have the session cookie (`_app_session`) included in the request headers so that the server can verify the auth status and return it.

Theoretically, this should work since the browser will attach all cookies with the domain matching my Rails server in the request sent.

However, when developing in `http://localhost:3000` and when I try to send a request to `http://localhost:3000/browser-extension/auth`, no cookies belonging to the `localhost` domain are included in the request headers despite them existing in Devtools 'Application' tab.

**what I have tried**

I have configured CORS in my backend Rails server using `rack-cors`

`config/initializers/cors.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins ['chrome-extension://{MY-BROWSER-EXTENSION-ID}']
    resource '/browser-extension/*', headers: :any, methods: [:get], credentials: true
  end
end
```

In my browser extension background service workers I am fetching it like so

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/browser-extension/auth", {
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

The CORS configuration should be working properly since I can send an arbitrary JSON back from `browser-extension/auth`. The issue is that the `_app_session` cookie is not attached in the request headers.

The `_app_session` cookie has attributes of `HttpOnly` and `SameSite=Lax`

**temporary solution**

I have used `ngrok` to create a secure tunnel to `http:localhost:3000` and directed all my browser extension requests to the `ngrok` proxy and this resolved my issues. The `_app_session` cookie is included in my request headers.

But I would like to find out why did it not work with `localhost` even though the cookie has the same attributes.